# How do I change pages and call a certain Javascript function with Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, flask

I am not sure if I worded my question correctly. I'm not actually sure how to go about this at all.

I have a site `load.html`. Here I can use a textbox to enter an ID, for example `123`, and the page will display some information (retrieved via a Javascript function that calls AJAX from the Flask server).

I also have a site, `account.html`. Here it displays all the IDs associated with an account.
I want to make it so if you click the ID in `account.html`, it will go to `load.html` and show the information required.

Basically, after I press the link, I need to change the URL to `load.html`, then call the Javascript function to display the information associated with the ID.

My original thoughts were to use variable routes in Flask, like `@app.route('/load/<int:id>')` instead of simply `@app.route('/load')`

But all `/load` does is show `load.html`, not actually load the information. That is done in the Javascript function I talked about earlier.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any ideas?

If I need to explain more, please let me know. Thanks!

To make this more clear, I can go to `load.html` and call the Javascript function from the web console and it works fine. I'm just not sure how to do this with variable routes in Flask (is that the right way?) since showing the information depends on some Javascript to parse the data returned by Flask.

Flask code loading `load.html`

```
@app.route('/load')
def load():
    return render_template('load.html')
```

Flask code returning information

```
@app.route('/retrieve')
def retrieve():
    return jsonify({
        'in':in(),
        'sb':sb(),
        'td':td()
    })
```

`/retrieve` just returns a data structure from the database that is then parsed by the Javascript and output into the HTML. Now that I think about it, I suppose the variable route has to be in retrieve? Right now I'm using AJAX to send an ID over, should I change that to `/retrieve/<int:id>`? But how exactly would I retrieve the information, from, example, `/retrieve/5`? In AJAX I can just have `data` under the success method, but not for a simple web address.

Comment: Can you show us your flask app code?

Comment: I added the flask app code.

Comment: My thought right now is that I have to parse the data and render it all in Flask. is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you are passing the data into retrieve from the browser url as

```
www.example.com/retrieve?Data=5
```

you can get the data value like

```
dataValue = request.args.get('Data')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify param in url like `/retrieve/<page>`

It can use several ways in flask.

One way is

```
@app.route('/retrieve/', defaults={'page': 0})
@app.route('/retrieve/<page>')
def retrieve():

    if page:
        #Do page stuff here

    return jsonify({
        'in':in(),
        'sb':sb(),
        'td':td()})
```

Another way is

```
@app.route('/retrieve/<page>')
def retrieve(page=0):

    if page:
        #Do your page stuff hear

    return jsonify({
        'in':in(),
        'sb':sb(),
        'td':td()
    })
```

[Note](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#variable-rules): You can specify converter also like `<int:page>`